# Storing array in session? How should I do this?

Tags: javascript, session, session-state

So I have a dynamically created playlist that users create by searching for songs. I want to make it so when the page is refreshed all the songs stay there.

What would be the best way to store the playlist?

I have tried using Persist.js but storing an array like:

```
[["title":"song name", "artist":"someartist"], ["title":"another song", "artist":"one more"]]
```

Always makes the array appear as:

```
["title", "song name", "artist", "someartist", "title"...]
```

Not what I want. Plus not sure if it is the best idea if the playlist gets large.

So when it be better to create a server session? Or just store all the songs into a database?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save the array as a JSON object, which is simply stored as a string. In this way, you can easily store it as a session variable.

```
$_SESSION['test'] = json_encode($myArray);

$loadedArray = json_decode($_SESSION['test']);
```

I'd recommend storing it in a database if you want the list to be stored for any length of time, especially if you don't know how large the list could get. Alternatively, you could just put a cap on the array length and discard all tracks after say the first 20.

Answer (score 1):

You could also store them as URL hash values and then on page load read them in and load the songs.

If the songs are being loaded through PHP you could set them as cookies and then have PHP read the cookie.

Additionally if they're being loaded through PHP and you don't want to use cookies you could have php echo an inline script (so that it's executed before the full page loads) that, if there are hash values in the URL redirects the user to a page where the hash values have been converted into GET values which can then be read by PHP.